# Como excluir registros automaticamente com postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, procedure

Recentemente conseguir pegar um projeto que se trata de um blog, o usuário irá realizar as postagens de vários noticias, porém eu estou utilizando o servidor **Heroku** com a conta gratuita que dá direito há somente 512 Megas de espaço, acima desse limite ele começar a cobrar.

No momento que o usuário fosse realizando as postagens, o banco obviamente começaria a ser mais utilizado, a minha ideia seria que quando o banco chegasse a 500 Mega de espaço utilizado ele começasse a deletar automaticamente os registros começando dos últimos registros, eu tenho quase certeza que isso é feito com uma **Procedure** ou uma **Triggers**, eu já tentei criar um algoritmo, mas parece que não funciona, eu fiz umas pesquisas e encontrei isso;

Esse algoritmo abaixo é para somente saber quanto de espaço tem minha base de dados;

```
SELECT pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)/1024/1024 AS size_in_mb 
FROM pg_database
WHERE pg_database.datname = 'seu_banco'
```

E encontrei essa fonte de pesquisa, mas não entendi como na prática isso pode funcionar

[PostgreSQL VACUUM: Limpando o Banco de dados](https://www.devmedia.com.br/postgresql-vacuum-limpando-o-banco-de-dados/29716)

O que preciso somente uma Trigger ou Procedure qu esteja rodando na minha base de dados e possa fazer isso pra mim, por favor alguém tem uma sugestão ou um algoritmo pronto que pudesse me passar ?

Answer (score 2):

O exemplo abaixo tem como objeto minha tabela *tabusuarios* do meu banco de dados *tempo*.
O meu banco de dados *tempo* tem 13 MB.

O intuito aqui é deletar o registro mais antigo da tabela de usuários, caso o banco de dados exceda em tamanho um valor determinado.
O valor que vou arbitrar é 10 MB.

Faço, primeiro, uma função (*TRIGGER FUNCTION*), via console do PGAdmin.

```
Uma TRIGGER FUNCTION é o que guarda o mecanismo de execução de algum procedimento, uma instrução SQL normalmente.
```

Como veremos, dentro da FUNCTION TRIGGER encontra-se um conjunto de instruções que efetivamente faz algo produtivo no banco de dados.

No seu caso, o procedimento é de deleção.

A função abaixo pergunta o tamanho do meu banco de dados. Se ele for maior que 10 MB (10 000 000 bytes), mandar executar um SQL para eliminar o registro que tem o ID (auto_increment) de número menor, que, claro, é o mais antigo.

Ela só permite deletar 1 registro, por causa da cláusula *LIMIT 1*.

No console do PGAdmin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
fun_deletaregistrousuarios()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT pg_database_size ('tempo') > 
'10000000') THEN
    DELETE FROM tabusuarios WHERE id = (SELECT id 
tabusuarios FROM tabusuarios ORDER BY id LIMIT 1);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

Codificada a função e executada a SQL de sua criação, faço o *TRIGGER*.

```
Um TRIGGER é um bloco de instruções pelo qual se vigia um evento qualquer numa tabela, disparando uma FUNCTION TRIGGER. Funciona como um despertador, que toca a campainha numa hora determinada. No nosso caso, vai 'despertar a função' caso alguma coisa aconteça com os dados da tabela.
```

No console do PGAdmin:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_vigia_usuarios AFTER INSERT 
ON  tabusuarios 
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
fun_deletaregistrousuarios();
```

No nosso caso, o evento é *AFTER INSERT*, isto é, se houver a inclusão de um único registro que seja na minha tabela de usuários, vai disparar o mecanismo.

```
O *trigger* é associado à tabela, porque é sobre ela que se vigia qualquer inserção.
```

Por curiosidade, no meu *schema* *public*, posso ver uma entrada nova na pasta 'Function Triggers', de nome *fun_deletaregistrousuarios*;

Também, dentro do mesmo *schema*, agora na 'pasta' *tables*, na 'subpasta' da tabela *tabusuarios*, tenho mais uma entrada, que é *Triggers*. Lá, encontro *tg_vigia_usuarios*.

```
Por fim, estando tudo pronto, no momento da inserção de um novo registro na tabela tabusuarios, um outro mais antigo foi deletado, uma vez que meu banco de dados tem 13 MB e o limite para o trigger provocar a função é de 10 MB.
```

Por outras palavras, como o meu banco de dados (13 MB) já supera em tamanho o valor do teste do bloco *IF* da minha função - que é provocada pelo trigger se o banco de dados for maior que 10 MB -  executa-se a instrução *DELETE* num registro antigo.

Claro está que minha abordagem não resolve exatamente o problema proposto, porque deleta apenas um registro e ele pode ser insuficiente para trazer o tamanho do banco de dados ao limite desejado, mas isto é um ajuste na TRIGGER FUNCTION.
Como sugestão, fazer um loop na deleção ou outro modo de abranger mais registros e testar após cada deleção o tamanho do banco pode ser uma saída.

É só um caminho para iniciar.

Ajustem-se os valores - como nome e instrução SQL do miolo da função e o evento no trigger - a qualquer outra necessidade.